# JBoss + Seam - exception after successful logging in - google didn't help

Tags: exception, jboss, seam

I have problems with loggin into a webapp. The app is working on the other machine. I use direct copy of a server (jboss)/webapp and I get this exception right after successful logging in, but before the view is rendered. JBoss AS 5.1.0, Seam 2.2.1. Do you have some ideas why is this not working on my machine?

Btw. Some other parts of the exception log mention the impossibility of creating session (SFSB).

```
org.jboss.seam.InstantiationException: Could not instantiate Seam component: congressBean
    at org.jboss.seam.Component.newInstance(Component.java:2144)
    at org.jboss.seam.Component.getInstance(Component.java:2021)
    at org.jboss.seam.Component.getInstance(Component.java:1983)
    at org.jboss.seam.Component.getInstance(Component.java:1977)
    at org.jboss.seam.Component.getInstanceFromFactory(Component.java:2073)
    at org.jboss.seam.Component.getInstance(Component.java:2011)
    at org.jboss.seam.Component.getInstance(Component.java:1983)
    at org.jboss.seam.Component.getInstance(Component.java:1977)
    at org.jboss.seam.Namespace.getComponentInstance(Namespace.java:55)
    at org.jboss.seam.Namespace.getComponentInstance(Namespace.java:50)
    at org.jboss.seam.el.SeamELResolver.resolveBase(SeamELResolver.java:148)
    at org.jboss.seam.el.SeamELResolver.getValue(SeamELResolver.java:51)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:54)
    at com.sun.faces.el.FacesCompositeELResolver.getValue(FacesCompositeELResolver.java:72)
    at org.jboss.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:44)
    at org.jboss.el.parser.AstNotEqual.getValue(AstNotEqual.java:21)
    at org.jboss.el.parser.AstAnd.getValue(AstAnd.java:21)
    at org.jboss.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:186)
    at com.sun.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:71)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.isRendered(UIComponentBase.java:390)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.renderChild(RendererBase.java:271)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.renderChildren(RendererBase.java:258)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.TabRendererBase.encodeChildren(TabRendererBase.java:113)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:837)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.renderChild(RendererBase.java:277)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.renderChildren(RendererBase.java:258)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.html.TabPanelRenderer.doEncodeChildren(TabPanelRenderer.java:285)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.html.TabPanelRenderer.doEncodeChildren(TabPanelRenderer.java:280)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.encodeChildren(RendererBase.java:120)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:837)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:930)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:148)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:837)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.renderChild(RendererBase.java:277)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.renderChildren(RendererBase.java:258)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.html.PanelRenderer.doEncodeChildren(PanelRenderer.java:220)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.html.PanelRenderer.doEncodeChildren(PanelRenderer.java:215)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.encodeChildren(RendererBase.java:120)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:837)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:930)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:933)
    at com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler.renderView(FaceletViewHandler.java:592)
    at org.ajax4jsf.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:100)
    at org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxViewHandler.renderView(AjaxViewHandler.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:110)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:266)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:510)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:83)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.IdentityFilter.doFilter(IdentityFilter.java:40)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.MultipartFilter.doFilter(MultipartFilter.java:90)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.ExceptionFilter.doFilter(ExceptionFilter.java:64)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:45)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:178)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:368)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:495)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.Ajax4jsfFilter.doFilter(Ajax4jsfFilter.java:56)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:60)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.HotDeployFilter.doFilter(HotDeployFilter.java:53)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:433)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Could not dereference object [Root exception is javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException]
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.getObjectInstanceWrapFailure(NamingContext.java:1504)
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:822)
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:686)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
    at org.jboss.seam.Component.instantiateSessionBean(Component.java:1400)
    at org.jboss.seam.Component.instantiate(Component.java:1364)
    at org.jboss.seam.Component.newInstance(Component.java:2122)
    ... 93 more
Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jboss.ejb3.cache.simple.SimpleStatefulCache.create(SimpleStatefulCache.java:423)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.stateful.StatefulContainer.createSession(StatefulContainer.java:397)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.session.SessionContainer.createSession(SessionContainer.java:679)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.proxy.impl.factory.session.stateful.StatefulSessionProxyFactoryBase.getNewSessionId(StatefulSessionProxyFactoryBase.java:276)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.proxy.impl.factory.session.stateful.StatefulSessionProxyFactoryBase.createProxyBusiness(StatefulSessionProxyFactoryBase.java:140)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.proxy.impl.objectfactory.session.SessionProxyObjectFactory.createProxy(SessionProxyObjectFactory.java:129)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.proxy.impl.objectfactory.session.stateful.StatefulSessionProxyObjectFactory.getProxy(StatefulSessionProxyObjectFactory.java:64)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.proxy.impl.objectfactory.ProxyObjectFactory.getObjectInstance(ProxyObjectFactory.java:158)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:304)
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.getObjectInstance(NamingContext.java:1479)
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.getObjectInstanceWrapFailure(NamingContext.java:1496)
    ... 99 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jboss.ejb3.EJBContainer.invokeCallback(EJBContainer.java:1123)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.EJBContainer.invokePostConstruct(EJBContainer.java:1133)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.EJBContainer.invokePostConstruct(EJBContainer.java:1144)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.stateful.StatefulContainer.create(StatefulContainer.java:149)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.cache.simple.SimpleStatefulCache.create(SimpleStatefulCache.java:402)
    ... 109 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.company.app.action.CongressBean.initCongressBean(CongressBean.java:534)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.LifecycleCallbackBeanMethodInterceptor.invoke(LifecycleCallbackBeanMethodInterceptor.java:69)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.ConstructionInvocation.invokeNext(ConstructionInvocation.java:79)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor$InvocationContext.proceed(InvocationContextInterceptor.java:138)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.EJBInvocationContext.proceed(EJBInvocationContext.java:44)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:56)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.Interceptor.postConstruct(Interceptor.java:194)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:74)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.Interceptor.postConstruct(Interceptor.java:194)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:74)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.Interceptor.postConstruct(Interceptor.java:194)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:74)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.Interceptor.postConstruct(Interceptor.java:194)
        at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:74)
    at org.jboss.seam.persistence.EntityManagerProxyInterceptor.postConstruct(EntityManagerProxyInterceptor.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.seam.util.Reflections.invoke(Reflections.java:22)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.Interceptor.postConstruct(Interceptor.java:194)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:74)
    at org.jboss.seam.persistence.HibernateSessionProxyInterceptor.postConstruct(HibernateSessionProxyInterceptor.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.seam.util.Reflections.invoke(Reflections.java:22)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.Interceptor.postConstruct(Interceptor.java:194)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:74)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.RootInterceptor.invoke(RootInterceptor.java:107)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.RootInterceptor.invokeAndHandle(RootInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SessionBeanInterceptor.postConstruct(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:114)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.LifecycleCallbackInterceptorMethodInterceptor.invoke(LifecycleCallbackInterceptorMethodInterceptor.java:80)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.ConstructionInvocation.invokeNext(ConstructionInvocation.java:79)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor.setup(InvocationContextInterceptor.java:88)
    at org.jboss.aop.advice.org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor_z_setup_23654984.invoke(InvocationContextInterceptor_z_setup_23654984.java)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.ConstructionInvocation.invokeNext(ConstructionInvocation.java:79)
    at org.jboss.aspects.currentinvocation.CurrentInvocationInterceptor.invoke(CurrentInvocationInterceptor.java:67)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.ConstructionInvocation.invokeNext(ConstructionInvocation.java:79)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.EJBContainer.invokeCallback(EJBContainer.java:1119)
    ... 113 more
```

EDIT:
Here's the second part of the stacktrace:

```
2011-03-24 11:24:52,859 ERROR [org.jboss.ejb3.proxy.impl.factory.session.stateful.StatefulSessionProxyFactoryBase] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-6) Could not obtain new Session ID from SFSB Container
javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jboss.ejb3.cache.simple.SimpleStatefulCache.create(SimpleStatefulCache.java:423)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.stateful.StatefulContainer.createSession(StatefulContainer.java:397)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.session.SessionContainer.createSession(SessionContainer.java:679)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.proxy.impl.factory.session.stateful.StatefulSessionProxyFactoryBase.getNewSessionId(StatefulSessionProxyFactoryBase.java:276)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.proxy.impl.factory.session.stateful.StatefulSessionProxyFactoryBase.createProxyBusiness(StatefulSessionProxyFactoryBase.java:140)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.proxy.impl.objectfactory.session.SessionProxyObjectFactory.createProxy(SessionProxyObjectFactory.java:129)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.proxy.impl.objectfactory.session.stateful.StatefulSessionProxyObjectFactory.getProxy(StatefulSessionProxyObjectFactory.java:64)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.proxy.impl.objectfactory.ProxyObjectFactory.getObjectInstance(ProxyObjectFactory.java:158)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:304)
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.getObjectInstance(NamingContext.java:1479)
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.getObjectInstanceWrapFailure(NamingContext.java:1496)
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:822)
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:686)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
    at org.jboss.seam.Component.instantiateSessionBean(Component.java:1400)
    at org.jboss.seam.Component.instantiate(Component.java:1364)
    at org.jboss.seam.Component.newInstance(Component.java:2122)
    at org.jboss.seam.Component.getInstance(Component.java:2021)
    at org.jboss.seam.Component.getInstance(Component.java:1983)
    at org.jboss.seam.Component.getInstance(Component.java:1977)
    at org.jboss.seam.Component.getInstanceFromFactory(Component.java:2073)
    at org.jboss.seam.Component.getInstance(Component.java:2011)
    at org.jboss.seam.Component.getInstance(Component.java:1983)
    at org.jboss.seam.Component.getInstance(Component.java:1977)
    at org.jboss.seam.Namespace.getComponentInstance(Namespace.java:55)
    at org.jboss.seam.Namespace.getComponentInstance(Namespace.java:50)
    at org.jboss.seam.el.SeamELResolver.resolveBase(SeamELResolver.java:148)
    at org.jboss.seam.el.SeamELResolver.getValue(SeamELResolver.java:51)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:54)
    at com.sun.faces.el.FacesCompositeELResolver.getValue(FacesCompositeELResolver.java:72)
    at org.jboss.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:44)
    at org.jboss.el.parser.AstNotEqual.getValue(AstNotEqual.java:21)
    at org.jboss.el.parser.AstAnd.getValue(AstAnd.java:21)
    at org.jboss.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:186)
    at com.sun.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:71)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.isRendered(UIComponentBase.java:390)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.renderChild(RendererBase.java:271)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.renderChildren(RendererBase.java:258)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.TabRendererBase.encodeChildren(TabRendererBase.java:113)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:837)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.renderChild(RendererBase.java:277)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.renderChildren(RendererBase.java:258)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.html.TabPanelRenderer.doEncodeChildren(TabPanelRenderer.java:285)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.html.TabPanelRenderer.doEncodeChildren(TabPanelRenderer.java:280)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.encodeChildren(RendererBase.java:120)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:837)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:930)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:148)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:837)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.renderChild(RendererBase.java:277)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.renderChildren(RendererBase.java:258)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.html.PanelRenderer.doEncodeChildren(PanelRenderer.java:220)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.html.PanelRenderer.doEncodeChildren(PanelRenderer.java:215)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.encodeChildren(RendererBase.java:120)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:837)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:930)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:933)
    at com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler.renderView(FaceletViewHandler.java:592)
    at org.ajax4jsf.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:100)
    at org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxViewHandler.renderView(AjaxViewHandler.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:110)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:266)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:510)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:83)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.IdentityFilter.doFilter(IdentityFilter.java:40)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.MultipartFilter.doFilter(MultipartFilter.java:90)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.ExceptionFilter.doFilter(ExceptionFilter.java:64)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:45)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:178)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:368)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:495)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.Ajax4jsfFilter.doFilter(Ajax4jsfFilter.java:56)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:60)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.HotDeployFilter.doFilter(HotDeployFilter.java:53)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:433)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Answer (score 1):

The stacktrace tells you what's wrong: line 534 of class CongressBean.java (within the initCongressBean method) has a nullpointerexception. You need to determine what reference within that line is null and why.

Comment: Yeah, but this:
`534   languageConverter = new LanguageConverter();`
calls this:
`public LanguageConverter() {
    map = new HashMap<String, Language>();
}`
which shouldn't cause any problems... or maybe I'm just too tired.

Comment: Shouldn't, but it is, I'm afraid. Is there a reason that HashMap can't be instantiated? Is the Language class available, for instance?

Comment: I guess it would throw then some kind of ClassNotFoundException. The whole server+app is a mirror copy from another machine, where it works.

Comment: That may be true, but it doesn't work here. You mentioned another error that prevents a session being created - maybe that's relevant? Not much more we can do to assist at this point.

Comment: Ok, I put another part of the log into the original post.

Answer (score 1):

You may have your source not in sync with the deployed binary as there's no way this line throws an NPE:

```
languageConverter = new LanguageConverter();
```

Please, post the full source of `initCongressBean` method so that we can guess where the NPE came from.

Comment: Oh man, that's actually true, and currently I don't have the source of this version. I'll try to get it and see what's going on in there.